# Bash: using the result of a diff in a if statement

Tags: bash, diff

I am writing a simple Bash script to detect when a folder has been modified.

It is something very close to:

```
ls -lR $dir > a
ls -lR $dir > b

DIFF=$(diff a b) 
if [ $DIFF -ne 0 ] 
then
    echo "The directory was modified"
```

Unfortunately, the if statement prints an error: [: -ne: unary operator expected

I am not sure what is wrong with my script, would anyone please be able to help me?

Thank you very much!

Jary

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
ls -lR $dir > a
ls -lR $dir > b

DIFF=$(diff a b) 
if [ "$DIFF" != "" ] 
then
    echo "The directory was modified"
fi
```

Comment: or more simply  if [ "$DIFF" ]

Comment: diff has exit status which can be tested directly, without using another executable namely '['.

Comment: The answer deserves some explanation about comparing exit code vs. comparing the output of the command.

Comment: This is **vastly** inefficient as opposed to using `cmp` instead. `diff` is a much slower and more expensive tool, and you only need to use it when you want to know **exactly what the difference is**, not whether there is one or not.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - `cmp` lacks functionality that might be needed in the comparison.   One example being ignoring lines in the comparison.

Comment: @AdrianLynch, the OP is explicitly using this for an "if" that determines -- true or false -- whether modification occurred. If one one wants to know which specific lines were added or removed, `comm` does that more efficiently than `diff` does, as it needs not make any effort to compute the shortest possible transform between the two files. (Indeed, in the case where files are pre-sorted, `comm`'s performance is `O(n)`; when that's not true and one needs to run `sort` in front, a good implementation is still far faster than `diff`). See [BashFAQ #36](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036).

Comment: @AdrianLynch, ...and beyond *that*, `comm` can run in a constant amount of memory, which `diff` cannot do. (`sort` compromises that somewhat, but the GNU version supports sorting different chunks of the input to different temporary files and then doing a merge sort to combine them, so `sort` too can run in bounded memory space whereas `diff` cannot).

Answer (score 65):

```
if ! diff -q a b &>/dev/null; then
  >&2 echo "different"
fi
```

Comment: This is the most direct way of doing the test. (Note: you should add a close quote to the echo command.)

Comment: diff may send messages to stderr too, like permission denied errors, depending on your version

Comment: This answer works perfectly, but I'm confused by the negation (`!`), given the diff manpage: _"Exit status is 0 if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble."_  Doesn't that mean it _should_ be working the other way around?  `if ! diff.. then echo "same"`?

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg bash's `if` operates differently than C. It does the conditional if the return is 0. Check out the man page for the `test` command - it returns 0 if true and 1 if false.

Answer (score 32):

You are looking for the return value of `diff` and not the output of `diff` that you are using in your example code.

Try this:

```
diff a b
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "The directory was modified";
fi
```

Comment: If you use this approach, be careful to do the test immediately after the 'diff' command. This is important as $? contain the return code of the LAST command.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't need to know what the changes are, `cmp` is enough.
Plus you can play with the syntactical trick provided by `&&` and `||` :

```
cmp a b || echo 'The directory was modified'
```

The instruction may be interpreted as:
"either a and b are equal, or i echo the message".

(The semantic of `&&` and `||` must be handled with care, but here it's intuitive).

Just for the sake of readability, i actually prefer to put it on two lines:

```
cmp a b \
  || echo 'The directory was modified'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DIFF=$(diff -u <(find dir1/ -type f -printf '%P\n' | sort) <(find dir2/ -type f -printf '%P\n' | sort))
if [ "$DIFF" ]; then
  echo "Directories differ"
  # Do other stuff here
fi
```

This uses one of my favorite bashisms, the `<()` process substitution.

The `$DIFF` variable holds a printable difference. If you want to show it to the end user, be sure to double-quote it, e.g. `echo "$DIFF"`.

If you want to only tell the user there was *any* difference, if can be shortened to something like `[ "$(diff ...)" ] && echo "Difference found"`

**Note**: I'm assuming the original question meant to have `dir1` and `dir2` to make a little more sense. If it was `dir` at time 0 and then `dir` at time 1, this approach obviously wouldn't work.