# Check for directory modifications using diff

Tags: bash, if-statement, diff

I'm getting started with bash-scripting and I am currently writing a script to backup a directory if the directory was modified since the last time it was backed-up . I am using the diff command to check for this, but I think I might not be using it right.

**EDIT**
The reason I am getting differences is because the files newFile and oldFile are being created in the directory which has the script and that is the same directory which I am trying to backup. How do I use diff such that it returns differences other than those 2 files ?

```
ls -lR $1 > oldFile

while [ 0 ]; 
do

    ls -lR $1 > newFile

    if [ ! diff newFile oldFile ] ; then
  echo "they differ"

else

    echo "they don't differ" 
fi

 done
```

Comment: Doesn't the output of `diff` tell you exactly why they differ?

Answer (score 1):

First, the if statement doesn't work at all. use:

```
if [ diff oldFile newFile ] ; then
    echo "they differ"
fi
```

Note the `[ ]` brackets! (note that they are not really 'brackets'. `[` is a shorty for the `test` command and `]` is the last argument to it. Crazy, but cool!

---

You can use

```
diff -rN OLD_DIR NEW_DIR
```

to get a recursive diff. `-N` also tracks new files

Also you might have a look at [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) and friends. Inotify is a mechanism in the Linux kernel that allows to register hooks when an inode (file or directory,...) has changed. Using `inotifywait` (and fiends) you are enabled to register a shell script that will be triggered at every file operation that takes place on a file / directory of interest. In that script you can doing backup directly after changes (if you want)

Comment: I made the change to my if statement and added [] , but now it goes into the else statement and always prints out they dont differ.
This is how the conditional statement is now 
if [ ! diff new old ] ; then
   echo "they differ"
 else
     
  echo "they don't differ" 
 fi

Comment: try: `if [ diff -RN DIRECTORY1 DIRECTORY2 ] ; then echo 'they differ' ; else echo "they don't differ"  fi`

Comment: I don't really understand your question's update. I don't know why you diff files when you need to know if a directory has changed. Use `-rN` as I suggested! Also have a look at `inotifywait`

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to use inotify ? I can't seem to figure out how to create a copy of a directory on modification.

Answer (score 0):

A small search would have revealed this: [Bash: using a the result of a diff in a if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611846/bash-using-a-the-result-of-a-diff-in-a-if-statement?rq=1).

```
DIFF=$(diff newfile oldfile) 
if [ "$DIFF" != "" ]; then
    ...
```

Comment: Is it because the directory listings are being written to the exact same directory? This way, it would always differ.

Comment: Besides, have you checked the link. There's more than one answer that does the trick.

Comment: No, the backup directory is different. Either way I am using diff on the exact same directory, but at different times. So in the beginning of the program it creates the file old, and then it sleeps for 5 seconds then creates the file new. So, it should say the files dont differ.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `md5deep` to hash the files in the directory and then hash the output of that command for a final checksum:

```
hash=$(md5deep -rs folder | md5sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Brackets around `diff` in your code are not mandatory, the idea being that the `if` statement tests by itself the return code of the command that follows. So no need to call `test` another time. You can also write:

```
if diff -q newFile oldFile &> /dev/null ; then...
```

(the redirection to /dev/null being here because  `diff` returns a - useless - output )