# Linux text match beep

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I want to have some utility that check my console output, and in case of some text match like "ERROR" make a beep or other type of event. Can somebody help me to find some?

Comment: Console output of a program? Or always? In case of a program, you can redirect the output of the program to a small script (see shell redirection), and in the script check for any text

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1. Redirect your output to a file.
2. Run a diff on that file versus the "truth data".  See here on how to use diff in an if statement: [Bash: using the result of a diff in a if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611846/bash-using-a-the-result-of-a-diff-in-a-if-statement)
3. If diff returns nothing, play a sound.  Details for sound playing can be found here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8607/how-can-i-play-a-sound-when-script-execution-is-ready

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Go one step further and make a monitoring utility that will email you after an error. Your email program will have a lot of beeps and popups for alerts.