# Run a bash command until diff between two files is non-empty

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a two versions of a program, say : `normalProgram` and `bruteProgram`.

I have an input generator for both of these : `programGenerator`

Now I want to do this:

- Put the output of `./programGenerator` into `input.txt` : `./programGenerator > input.txt`
- Redirect `input.txt` as the input of `normalProgram` : `cat input.txt | ./normalProgram`

  - Put the output of `./normalProgram` into `op1.txt` : `(cat input.txt | ./normalProgram) > op1.txt`
- Similar thing for `./bruteProgram` :

  - `(cat input.txt | ./bruteProgram) > op2.txt`
- Now I want to compare `op1.txt` and `op2.txt` : `diff op1.txt op2.txt`

The whole command will look like this:

```
./programGenerator > input.txt &&
(cat input.txt | ./normalProgram) > op1.txt &&
(cat input.txt | ./bruteProgram) > op2.txt &&
diff op1.txt op2.txt
```

So this is a one time command.

I want to run this until `diff op1.txt op2.txt` gives a non-empty response.

I tried putting `diff op1.txt op2.txt` as the condition for until (or while, just to check whether the conditional is correct)

But this didn't work, and I got an error that, that is not a correct conditional.

Example:

```
while [diff normalOp.txt bruteOp.txt]
do
echo "hello"
done
```

This is giving me the error:

```
zsh: bad pattern: [diff
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Bash conditional based on exit code of command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command/49850110). Also, if you did need to use square brackets, [you'd need spaces around them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733437/getting-command-not-found-error-while-comparing-two-strings-in-bash). Finally, `(cat input.txt | ./normalProgram) > op1.txt` can be simplified to `./normalProgram < input.txt > op1.txt` (which is also more efficient).

Answer (score 0):

I just had to remove the square brackets from the condition:

```
while diff normalOp.txt bruteOp.txt  
do
echo "hello"
done
```

And this started working.

---

The exact bash command in this case would be:

```
while diff op1.txt op2.txt
while> do
while> ./programGenerator > input.txt   
while> (cat input.txt | ./normalProgram) > op1.txt
while> (cat input.txt | ./bruteProgram) > op2.txt
while> done
```

Comment: The syntax error was one problem, but your current logic is "while diff produces some output, do a thing." What you have stated in the question would be "while diff produces no output, do a thing." [This is for Bash, but should be similar in Zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611846/bash-using-the-result-of-a-diff-in-a-if-statement), though you could also make it simpler using `until` instead of `while`.